# How can i edit a .class file from a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a .jar file and I have decompiled it using Java Decompiler, I want to modify a .class file from the .jar and recompile it. I tried to use eclipse to copy the code but it has many imports so i can't recompile it int a .class file without the imports. Is there any other solution? Is there a better approach to this ?

Comment: If you can't recompile it into a .class file without the imports, then recompile it into a .class file *with* the imports.

Comment: Please specify which problem exactly are you trying to solve. Why you need to decompile and recompile the class file? Probably your original problem can be solved in easier way. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The real question you have to ask is why you want to do this ? It's not a good practice at all to modify things this way...

Comment: I am trying to skip over a licensing procedure, it's not black-hat it's white-hat hacking. It's for a security improvement.

Comment: You should be able to load the bytes from the class contained in the jar file, manipulate its content via a byte-manipulation framework ([javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/), [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/), ...) and load the manipulated bytes via a custom classloader into the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should on the first hand prevent these type of Fixes and Changes. But if it required, you should have all the import class's code also in order to recompile the decompiled class, as they will be required at the time of compiling, but that might not be a feasible option.

The other approach you can use is a Class Editor, which let you edit directly a class file.
[Get It Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classeditor/)

Answer (score -4):

the import directive is "sugar syntax".  The compiler adds the correct package to all class references.